# Ho do i convert this code into PostgreSQL Store Procedure?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. I want to converter or add this code to Store Procedure.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(i) AS (
  SELECT * FROM unnest((select regexp_split_to_array('signature',''))::char[])
), cte AS (
     SELECT i AS combo, i, 1 AS ct 
     FROM t 
   UNION ALL 
     SELECT cte.combo || t.i, t.i, ct + 1
     FROM cte, t
     WHERE ct <= 8
       AND position(t.i in cte.combo) = 0
) 
SELECT distinct cc.combo,ww.word 
FROM cte cc 
   inner join words ww ON ww.word=cc.combo 
WHERE length(combo)>1 
  AND ww.source_id in(1,2,19,21,24,26,33,34) 
ORDER BY cc.combo ASC;
```

Comment: And why do you want to do that? you could simply put it into a view. And besides a set returning _function_ would most probably be the better choice

Comment: actually,this code return all anagrams for given words (in above code i have passed 'signature' ). I want to write procedure where i can simply Exec this procedure by passing single word. (Call Proc_Name(word)). and it will return all Anagrams for given word.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it into a function:

```
create function generate_anagrams(p_word text)
  returns table(combo text, word text)
as
$$
WITH RECURSIVE t(i) AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM unnest((select regexp_split_to_array(p_word,''))::char[])
), cte AS (
     SELECT i AS combo, i, 1 AS ct 
     FROM t 
   UNION ALL 
     SELECT cte.combo || t.i, t.i, ct + 1
     FROM cte, t
     WHERE ct <= 8
       AND position(t.i in cte.combo) = 0
) 
SELECT distinct cc.combo,ww.word 
FROM cte cc 
   inner join words ww ON ww.word=cc.combo 
WHERE length(combo)>1 
  AND ww.source_id in(1,2,19,21,24,26,33,34) 
ORDER BY cc.combo ASC
$$
language sql;
```

You can use it like this:

```
select *
from generate_anagrams('signature');
```